# Configure HTTP Sampler without port number In JMeter

Tags: jmeter, http-headers, httprequest, httpresponse, port-number

Using JMeter, I have recorded a HTTP recorded script for performance test.

Can I configure HTTP Samplers without specifying a port number?

Comment: If you had done some research you would know the [answer](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-jmeter-to-record-test-scenarios).

By the way, not you cannot becasue you need a port to listen to in order to record the requests. Default port for http is 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave port number field empty in JMeter.

It will use default port number which is 80 for [HTTP request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

> Port the web server is listening to. Default: 80